# Is it possible to hide an html element if dynamic content requires more space?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I would like to hide an html Element (in my case a headline) only when the dynamic content of the site expands so far vertically that a scrollbar would appear. I am aware how to hide an element but I don't know how to trigger the event. I am searching for something like the @media rule in css, only that it shouldn't be triggered on the viewport resolution, but the size of the content (vertically).
Does anyone know a solution to this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your best bet is to use JavaScript to determine the size of the content, and when it reaches whatever threshold you set, toggle the visibility to hidden.

Comment: Thank you very much, works exactly as I need it! Somehow, I didn't think of JavaScript because the dynamic content is produced via PHP. If anyone is looking for the same thing, here is a working Javscript solution (no JQuery needed):

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nicks comment I figured out a solution.
If anyone is looking for the same thing, here is a working Javascript solution (no JQuery needed):

```
var callback = function(){
    // Handler when the DOM is fully loaded
    // Check if the body height is bigger than the clients viewport
    if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight) {
              // Assign a class with display:none (in my case 'hide')
              document.getElementById("headline").className = 'hide';
          }
  };
// This part ensures that the script will be loaded once the site is loaded  
  if (
      document.readyState === "complete" ||
      (document.readyState !== "loading" && !document.documentElement.doScroll)
  ) {
    callback();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
  }
```

With help by https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-document-ready-plain-javascript/